# Laravel 8, how to upload more than one image at a time

Tags: php, sql, laravel, image, upload

I want to upload more than one image at a time through an  in Laravel 8 to my SQL database, and I am not able to do it. I have managed to upload only one, but when I try with more I get failure.

**My Database**

*Imagenes*

| id | nombre | id_coche |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | name.jpg | 0004 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**My Code**

*Blade with the Form*

```
                   @foreach ($Vehiculo as $obj) /*this is to take the Car ID*/
                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('añadirImagen')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text">ID</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_coche" value="{{$obj->id}}" style="background: white" required readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen" required multiple/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">AÑADIR IMAGENES</button>
                                    </div>                           
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        @endforeach
```

*Controller*

*"To upload only one image"*

```
    public function añadirImagen(Request $request){

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'id_coche' => 'required',
            'nombre.*' => 'mimes:image'
        ]);

        $data = $request->input();

        $id_coche = $data['id_coche'];

        $Imagenes= new Imagenes;

        $Imagenes->id_coche = $id_coche;

        if($request->file("imagen")!=null){
            $nombre = $request->file('imagen');
                $nombreFoto = $nombre->getClientOriginalName();
                $nombre->move('img/Coches/', $nombreFoto);
                $Imagenes->nombre = $nombreFoto;
        }

        $Imagenes->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('error','Se han añadido las imagenes correctamente.');
    }
}
```

*"My attempt to upload more than one"*

```
public function añadirImagen(Request $request){

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'id_coche' => 'required',
            'imagen.*' => 'mimes:image'
        ]);

        $data = $request->input();

        $id_coche = $data['id_coche'];

        $Imagenes= new Imagenes;

        $Imagenes->id_coche = $id_coche;

        if($request->hasfile("imagen")){
            $nombre_img = $request->file('imagen');
            foreach($nombre_img as $nombre) {
                $nombreFoto = $nombre->getClientOriginalName();
                $nombre->move('img/Coches/', $nombreFoto);
                
                $Imagenes->nombre = $nombreFoto;
            }
        }

        $Imagenes->save();
```

When doing this, it adds in the database a single row, with the correct id_coche, the Auto_Increment does well the ID, but the name remains NULL.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have:

`<input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen" required multiple/>`

and it needs to be:

`<input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen[]" required/>`

multiple attribute is not required.
Then you can do in your controller:

```
if($request->hasfile('imagen')) {
     foreach($request->file('imagen') as $file)
        {
            ...
        }
}
```